# Writing a character array to an element does not print the first letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to write out one character at a time to an element from an array of words. I loop through an array of words, breaking each word up into a character array. From there, I loop through the character array to jQuery.append each letter to a target element. For any word but the first in the loop, the first letter is not being written to the element. Console.log(letter) shows that the script is picking up on the letter. I think it may be due to me fading the target element out and back in after each word.

```js
var words = ["demo", "sample", "taco", "potato"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  typeStuff();
});

function typeStuff() {
  //if the type target element does not exist, create it. Runs once.
  if (!$("#typeTarget").length) {
    $("#typeHere").append("<span id='typeTarget'></span>");
  }

  //Create a string of tbe next word, then arrayify it.
  var w = words.shift();
  var wordAsArray = w.split("");

  //create a 450 ms interval to type each word out.
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    //First, check if no letters are left.
    if (wordAsArray.length == 0) {
      //If no letters are left, see if there's another word to pickup
      if (words.length == 0) {
        //Clear the interval, your work is done. Good job, scripto.
        window.clearInterval(interval);
      } else {
        //Clear the interval and run the delete function.
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        deleteStuff();
      }
    } else {
      //If any letters are left, get the next letter and append it to #typeTarget
      var letter = wordAsArray.shift();
      $("#typeTarget").append(letter);
    }
  }, 450);
}

function deleteStuff() {

  //Fade #typeTarget out, delete its contents, then show it again.
  $("#typeTarget").fadeOut(500, function() {
    $("#typeTarget").html("");
    $("#typeTarget").css({
      display: "inline"
    });
  });

  //Call the typeStuff function again to write the next word.
  typeStuff();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="titleText">This is a <span id="typeHere"></span></span>
```

Comment: Right, your fade-out takes 500 milliseconds, but the first iteration of the interval timer happens 50 milliseconds before that.

Comment: Hey, thanks Pointy! I updated the fadeout to 300 MS and tat fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

As Pointy pointed out:

> Right, your fade-out takes 500 milliseconds, but the first iteration of the interval timer happens 50 milliseconds before that.

Correcting the fade-out to 300 milliseconds corrected this.

Comment: And here is +10 for copy-pasting. But it's not good practice! You may get downvotes for that! Welcome to SO!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir -> Thank you for the information - how should I handle answers in comments in the future?

Comment: If you're the owner of the question, then post you feedback as a comment! not as an answer.